# What's the probability of the weight of an order don't exceed 1.2kg, knowing it exceeds 0.5kg?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I just want some simple answers to some tricky questions.

Firstly, how could I represent the answer for the question:
**"What's the probability of the weight of an order don't exceed 1.2kg, knowing it exceeds 0.5kg ?"**

Is this right (?):
$$P(X < 1.2 | X > 0.5) $$

This expression makes some sense to me. But it doesn't give me the right solution. So what's wrong in my thought?

Another example of a tricky question:

Suppose a bank transaction is running 1 minute ago, what is the probability that it will take another 15 seconds to complete the transaction? The Variable represents the time needed to do a bank transaction, in minutes.

Would it be(?):

$$P(X < 1.25 | X > 1) $$

**or**

$$P(X > 1.25 | X > 1) $$

The first one makes more sense to me, because we dont want to exceed that 15 seconds.

Comment: @lulu can you help me? I particularly like your answers.

Comment: For your first question, in either case it should be $P(X<1.2|X>0.5)$. You are asking for probability that total weight (waiting time for train) is less than $1.2$, and the conditional part of the probability is just extra information that you have. You are still looking for the same event, you just have a bit more information now.

Comment: For your second question, I don't understand the event you are looking for - are you trying to say the bank transaction will take **at most** another 15 seconds? If so then yes $P(X < 1.25 | X > 1)$ is correct.

Comment: @JohnDoe say that a train has left the station 1 hour ago, what is the probability that we have to wait at least more 1 hour? Ans: P(X>2|X>1)

Comment: @JohnDoe the second question is exactly how it has been made to me in one exam, I would consider **"at most"**, but it doesn't give me the right solution

Comment: @JohnDoe I deleted the time variable example, to don't make confusion. But it is wrong anyway. :\

Comment: Yes, what you just said about the train probabilities is correct - the way I interpreted it was "what is the probability the total wait time for a train is $1.2hrs$ given you've already waited $0.5hrs$". But you seem to get that, so not a problem there.

Comment: @JohnDoe exactly. You said something that helps me, which is: "**the total**". The total wait can't exceed 1.2 kg, so my answer would be correct!

Comment: I suppose for the bank transaction, the question could mean to say it will still take another 15 seconds, or more, in which case $P(X > 1.25 | X > 1)$ would work.

Comment: @JohnDoe about the second question, I think you are correct, there is a misinformation, but it could possible mean that they would need at least more 15 seconds, but I interpreted **at most** 15 seconds.

Comment: Is there a nonzero probability that the weight can be exactly 1.2 kg? "Doesn't exceed 1.2 kg" would be $X\le 1.2$ where you've written $X<1.2$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm X is a continuous variable, with normal distribution, so it doesn't matter.